# Imported products not visible in OpenCart admin panel?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, opencart

Benn struggling with this issue for some time now. I have used a mod for importing a CSV file with my products to my OpenCart installation. The mod is called [CSV import Pro](http://opencart.hostjars.com/csv-import-pro)

Then products are visible on the front end an I can see them in the db table as well. Only problem I have is that they are not visible in my admin panel which is pretty strange.

Has anybody encountered this problem before? The company that I purchased the mod from are not the quickest when coming to supporting the mod.

All ideas, tips and resources are welcome.

Comment: Is there something in the database I'm missing to set? All seems fine.

Comment: After some digging I guess it has to be some field in the DB that is not set. When I add a product manually it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw something similar to this a while back and it turned out that the start date and end date values were missing for the products for their availability. Obviously I can't guarantee that this is the issue, but I would recommend you check that each and every value is being set for the products. I've not used CSV import Pro personally but I believe it's pretty popular and is likely due to missing data that it's not showing properly

Comment: Thanks, I did just that and the problem I had was the different languages layers. The name was only imported into English and not the other languages. When imported to all it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue for a long time. Using Import/Export Tool with multiple languages. Basically I was importing just one of the languages, it worked fine on the front end and I was able to see all products but I could only see two products at the back-end. My back-end language was English and my Front End - Bulgarian. It picked up the Bulgarian but unless your back-end is also set to the same language you will experience problems. Other option is just populate other language columns as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after looking for some hours I found the "guilty" table , 
it's the

> produt_to_store

table
set your product_id to the default store id (0) and voila !

```
INSERT INTO `product_to_store` (`product_id`, `store_id`) VALUES ('58366', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using another mod to extract and import from a Zencart database to Opencart. All customers were imported but did not show up in Admin, although viewable in the db table.  Turned out that the customer_group_id was 8 (presumably in Zencart) and the necessary id number in Opencart is 1.  Updated the customer_group_id column to show 1 instead of 8 and all the records became visible in Admin.  I found this out by creating new customers records and then comparing them to imported ones to see any differences.